# Increasing working memory in Postgres does not improve query performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I am very new to database administration and could use any advice from more expert users of PostgreSQL

My database is an AWS RDS db.m4.large whose specification are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html)

My queries against one of the larger tables in the database (330 million rows) are running extremely slow and/or timing out, even when I am have a query such as

```
SELECT(DISTINCT value) FROM mytable;
```

where there are only 4 or 5 unique values in the `value` column.  It is not indexed.

`pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid))` shows the size of the table to be **118 GB**

Even when setting `work_mem` to 240 MB, which should allow Postgres to do larger in-memory sorts, the query is equally as slow

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT(DISTINCT value) FROM mytable;`
also times out

What does one do to optimize memory usage for querying on a sufficiently large database?  Which pg settings would I need to monitor and/or configure differently?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but: putting the select list between parentheses is completely useless. `select distinct column from...` is the same thing as `select (distinct column) from`.

Comment: Do you have an index on that column?

Comment: "EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT(DISTINCT value) FROM mytable; also times out"  Change the time out.

Comment: It should probably be using a hash aggregate rather than a sort.  What does EXPLAIN without ANALYZE show?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It is actually worse than useless, the parentheses introduce a syntax error.  Which means we don't know what query he is actually trying to run.  I wonder if it is really a `count(distinct value)`

Comment: FWIW, `SELECT (DISTINCT value) FROM mytable;` gives an error in PostgreSQL versions 8.4 - 11. This syntax works `SELECT DISTINCT(value) FROM mytable;` (and is, IMHO, by far the most legible) - see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a88e63064c5ebda76253077ff5e3f79c). The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in the fiddle is worthless, because there are too few records - the `INDEX` will be ignored. I'd try indexing the field!